# Django template : {% if %} tag can't get it to work

Tags: django, django-templates

I am looking for a way in order my templates can recognize an attribute from my extended userprofile, specifically if he is an affiliate and show different content in the templates whether he is an affiliate or not. Is there an other approach to this like to build an decorator?

i have worked with other {%if%} tags like this built-in auth request `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`

models.py   project/useprofile/  , the book is in an other app project/book

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    affiliate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

add_book.html

```
{%extends 'base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content1 %}
{% if userprofile.profile.affiliate = True %}
<h1>New post</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^book/add/$', 'book.views.addbook', name='addbook'),
```

views.py

```
def addbook(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = BookForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        book = form.save(commit=False)
        book.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = BookForm()

return render(request, 'add_book.html',
    {'form':form,
 })
```

UPDATE: i found a simple solution to my problem, just needed to put `{% if user.profile.affiliate %}` in my template since i have extended the django user profile and affiliate is boolean so i do not need do the equal == part since it passes if its `True` , but i am still looking for other options available

Comment: `=` is assignment, not equality comparison (which is `==`).

Comment: changed it but still no results. i think the problem is in my views , i need to  get the object.profile.affiliate in a context , i was maybe thinking somehow to write an view

Comment: i was thinking somehow to write an view `def isaffiiate(request)`  that   works like ` {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}`